# What kind of experiments could you do to see which end of a microtubule is most dynamic?

Tags: cell-biology

I'm stuck between two ideas. Not sure which one of them would be best.

1. Do a FRAP on the middle of a MT. If it grows from the + end, that section will remain dark. If it grows from the - end, existing fluorescent tubulin will be pushed into the photobleached area. However, how would I be able to tell if the middle region is dynamic using a FRAP?
2. Introduce GFP-Tubulin into a cell. See where existing microtubules begin to fluoresce as new subunits are added.

Do either of these sound reasonable? Any better ideas?

Comment: This sure seems like a homework assignment. The methods for experiments like these were all published by the early '90's

Comment: As i remember, it has been shown that MTs are virtually indestructible in the middle. I'd say both sounds reasonable, but as soon as you start planning experiment, you get into trouble. FRAP seems most likely to succeed. Another one is FCS -- see where in the cell GPF-tubulin is most stable, e.g. closer to soma or axonal terminal (in neuron)